# Elasticsearch Single analyzer across multiple index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have time-based indices

students-2018

students-2019

students-2020

I have defined 1 analyzer with synonyms, I want to reuse the same analyzer across multiple indexes, how do I achieve that?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja your solution worked for newly created indices, but it didn't reflect changes for existing indices (please help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an index template and then create your custom analyzer with that template which includes all your `student` indices.

You can add your index-pattern in below index template call as mention in [the official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html).

**Sample index template def**

```
{
    "index_patterns": ["student-*"],
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_custom_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "html_strip"
                    ],
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now all your student indices like `students-2018` , `students-2019` will have this `my_custom_analyzer` which is defined in the index template.

Create a student index **without any setting and analyzer like**

```
http://{{you-es-hostname}}/student-2018
```

And then check its setting using `GET http://{{you-es-hostname}}/student-2018`, which would give below output and includes the analyzer created in the index template.

```
{
    "student-2018": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {},
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "student-2018",
                "creation_date": "1588653678067",
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_custom_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding"
                            ],
                            "char_filter": [
                                "html_strip"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "kjGEgKCOSJeIlrASP-RaMQ",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7040299"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `template` should be [`index_patterns`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) instead

Comment: @Val, its more of a best practice, works without it as well. would ass it as well, Thanks

Comment: All I meant is that to be future-proof (i.e. for people coming to this question in the future), it might be better not to use things we already know are deprecated. It's not a "best practice", it's a deprecated field name since ES 6.0. Thanks for updating it.

Comment: @Val, ahh, didn't know its deprecated, thanks for correcting me , your are welcome always :)

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja This seems to work only with newly created indices, the settings did not reflect with existing indices (please help)

Comment: @KaushikJ, yeah it would not work for existing index and template is used when you create a index using the template, so it wouldn't include the existing index. you need to create a create a new index , you can use the reindex API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html